# Email template displays VML and HTML code redundantly

Tags: html, css, vml

I have a simple HTML Email Template with some VML in it (for positioning and rendering on Outlook specifically). Issue is, when viewing the email on Outlook, it shows both the VML items and the regular HTML items. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
<title></title>
<!--[if mso]>
<noscript>
    <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
</noscript>
<![endif]-->
<style>
    table, td, div, h1, p {font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<table role="presentation" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border:0;border-spacing:0;background:#ffffff;">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0;">
        <table role="presentation" style="width:602px;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #cccccc;border-spacing:0;text-align:left;">
        <tr>
            <!--[if mso]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="position: relative; width: 1100px; height: 170px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="https://www.google.se/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
                <v:textbox style="v-text-anchor:bottom" inset="0,0,0,0">
                    <div style="position: relative; text-align: center;">
                        <font color="red">
                            <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 20px;font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 50px;">
                                <p>&nbsp;My VML Text Here!</p>
                            </div>
                        </font>
                    </div>
                </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
            <!-- Fallback for non-Microsoft email clients -->
            <td align="center" style="padding:40px 0 30px 0;">
                <div style="position: relative; text-align: center;">      
                    <img src="https://www.google.se/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt="" width="1100" style="height: 170px;display:block;" />
                    <p style="position: absolute; bottom: 8px; left: 16px; color: red; font-size: 50px">My Regular Text Here!</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Snap from Outlook:

[image: outlookView]

Anybody knows why is it showing both regular HTML and VML text at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Anybody knows why?"*

- Your `<!--[if mso]>` conditional-comment does not *hide* the Google logo image in Outlook.

  - [You need to wrap the non-Outlook parts in their own conditional-comment](https://stackoverflow.design/email/base/mso/):
- Also, your HTML is invalid: `<tr>` can only have `<th>` or `<td>` children, but you've got a `<v:rect>` as a child of `<tr>` - so I've corrected that too:
- And you should not be using `<font color="red">` anymore - it isn't 1995 anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
<title></title>
<!--[if mso]>
<noscript>
    <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
</noscript>
<![endif]-->
<style>
    table, td, div, h1, p {font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<table role="presentation" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border:0;border-spacing:0;background:#ffffff;">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0;">
        <table role="presentation" style="width:602px;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #cccccc;border-spacing:0;text-align:left;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="padding:40px 0 30px 0;">.

<!--[if mso]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="position: relative; width: 1100px; height: 170px;">
                        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://www.google.se/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
                        <v:textbox style="v-text-anchor:bottom" inset="0,0,0,0">
                            <div style="position: relative; text-align: center; color: red;">
                                <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 20px;font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 50px;">
                                    <p>&nbsp;My VML Text Here!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
            
                    <div style="position: relative; text-align: center;">      
                        <img src="https://www.google.se/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt="" width="1100" style="height: 170px;display:block;" />
                        <p style="position: absolute; bottom: 8px; left: 16px; color: red; font-size: 50px">My Regular Text Here!</p>
                    </div>
<!--<![endif]-->

            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hahaha that last part made me laugh. Thanks Dai!